# How to prove $\limsup(A_n\setminus A_{n+1})=\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a set sequence $\{A_n\}$, I want to prove $$\limsup(A_n\setminus A_{n+1})=\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n).$$
I  wonder how to use the def $\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=i}^\infty A_n$ to prove it.

Here's my proof from another aspect:

define a map $$A:X\to\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N},$$$$x\mapsto(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n,\cdots),$$ the mapping rule is if $x\in A_i,a_i=1$, for others $a_i=0.$

Then:

- $x\in\limsup(A_n\setminus A_{n+1})=\limsup(A_n\cap A_{n+1}^c)$ iff the ordered pair $(1,0)$ appears infinitely often in the sequence $A(x)$
- $x\in\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)=\limsup(A_{n+1}\cap A_n^c)$ iff the ordered pair $(0,1)$ appears infinitely often in the sequence $A(x)$,

and those two situations are the same.

Comment: Your proof is fine. What is your question?

Comment: I am wondering if I can use the definition of limsup to solve

Comment: Just do the same thing you've already done: replace $A_n \setminus A_{n+1}$ with $A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c$ in the definition and use what you know about the interactions of unions and intersections.